# Gradle is not Compatible with library

Tags: java, android, jar, android-gradle-plugin

i'm developing an android application that contain .jar file which company give it to me and it usage is for background Thread.

but when i add this jar to my project libs folder i get this error

```
 Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':hc:preDexDebug'
.>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
```

i have searched this Error a lot i have seen these Q&A s:

[Error: Gradle: execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847482/error-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug)

[Build error ,Gradle -> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. > org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351191/build-error-gradle-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug-org)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

[Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

[why java.exe exit with value 1 in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957412/why-java-exe-exit-with-value-1-in-android-studio)

but none of them works for me .

this is my module gradle file :

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "androidclient.hc"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

**NOTE**:

**1:** when i remove the company .jar project works perfect with no error so i know cause is .jar of course

**2:** this jar does not build with gradle and it compiles with JDK8 (Which i used too)

**3:** i have tried deleting JDK and install it again and also i've checked for duplicate usage of .jar

**4:** i have used JDK8 & SDK 5.1 & intelliJ 14.1

this .jar is too important for project and i have to use it (No jar , no project) .
well how can i solve this error ? should i tell company to compile their .jar with gradle or what ?

**(if you think more info is needed for answer please tell me i will add it)**

Comment: try to add `compile files('libs/company.jar');`

Comment: run gradle wrapper from command line with --info option. E,g, `./gradlew --info clean assembleDebug `. It should output detailed error messages.

Comment: @MD i have check it no Difference